# Wordpress: access to CSS file

Tags: css, wordpress, dashboard

I am a layman and I had a dispute with the person that built my wordpress site who has removed the CSS file so that the design of the site has been changed. He registered the template with Wordpress but I have all the codes for the dashboard for wordpress. My question is how can I restrict his access to this file?

Joel

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like he either has an admin account for your wordpress install or FTP access. If you made an admin him or he made it himself on WP, I would either delete the user or change the password (if he has the main PW).

The same basically goes if he has FTP access.